# javascript error ReferenceError: is not defined error | want to open a link in a new window using JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am getting below error

> Reference Error: xxxxfunctionname is not defined

when I call a function from `<a>` tag

for instance,

html tag

```
<a class="linkType2" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:abc_openthislink('http url')">abc</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function abc_openthislink(url)
    {
        window.open(url);   
    }
</script>
```

Is there something very obvious that I am missing here. Please correct me if you can.

Comment: remove javascript before your method name and try

Comment: Done that still the same issue :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ydx6qza1/

Comment: check link above which one i defined on fiddle

Comment: thanks for the solution I tweak it a bit  :)  to achieve new window thing though target="_blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<script>` tag in the header tag. When anchor element is created the function `abc_openthislink()` was not available, so onclick  event handler doesn't have a reference to the function.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avt3xpgt/1/)